# How to use cl-annot in Slime (to define another view in Lucerne)

Tags: common-lisp, slime

How to compile a function that uses a [cl-annot](https://github.com/m2ym/cl-annot) annotation ?

Use case:

[Lucerne](http://eudoxia.me/lucerne/docs/example--a-twitter-clone.html) uses it to define routes:

```
@route app "/profile/:username"
(defview profile (username)
  (let* ((user (utweet.models:find-user username))
         ;; The user's timeline
         (user-tweets (utweet.models:user-tweets user))
         ;; Is the user viewing his own profile?
         (is-self (string= (lucerne-auth:get-userid)
                           username)))
    (render-template (+profile+)
                     :user user
                     :tweets (display-tweets user-tweets)
                     :is-self is-self)))
```

I made it work with one view. But writing a second one and compiling it with `C-c-c` would not work. I installed `slime-annot.el` for emacs, but I only get

`The variable @ROUTE is unbound.
[Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]`

I did wrote `(annot:enable-annot-syntax)` at the beginning.

So this a blocking point :/ How can we define new stuff using cl-annot ?

Thanks

ps: [related issue](https://github.com/eudoxia0/lucerne/issues/16)

**edit**: more about the file structure: I created a project with Lucerne's project creator, this is the beginning of my main file:

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage lucerne-books
  (:use :cl
        :lucerne
        :cl-arrows
        :str)
  (:export :app)
  (:documentation "Main lucerne-books code."))
(in-package :lucerne-books)
(annot:enable-annot-syntax)

;;; App

(defapp app
  :middlewares ((clack.middleware.static:<clack-middleware-static>
                 :root (asdf:system-relative-pathname :lucerne-books #p"assets/")
                 :path "/static/")))

;;; Templates

(djula:add-template-directory
 (asdf:system-relative-pathname :lucerne-books #p"templates/"))

(defparameter +index+ (djula:compile-template* "index.html"))

;;; Views

@route app "/" ;; first created: it works
(defview index ()
  (render-template (+index+)
                   :foo "you"))

@route app "/rst" ;; this view won't work, not accessible
(defview index ()
  (render-template (+index+)
                   :foo "rst"))

@route app "/following/:username"  ;; this one neither
(defview user-following (username)
  (let ((user username))
    (render-template (+index+)
                     :foo user)))
```

Comment: I do not know Lucrene but I have used cl-annot without issues, recently. Do you have inserted "(annot:enable-annot-syntax)" at the beginning of the file as stated in the doc? Could you provide more infos about your file structure?

Comment: yes I do enabled the annot syntax. I edited my question with more info on my code and the file structure.

Comment: it works with `(syntax:use-syntax :annot)` which I found on a caveman project. Don't as me why !

Comment: Great to hear you found a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different notation on a Caveman project. It doesn't appear on cl-annot's doc, but it works:

```
(syntax:use-syntax :annot)
```

I can now `C-c C-c` new routes.